# Issue with escape_javascript with Elixir Phoenix

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to use [escape_javascript/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#escape_javascript/1), but am getting an error.

Here is my 'poster_controller.ex' action:

```
def index(conn, params) do
  posts = Repo.all(Post)
  render conn, %{posts: posts}
end
```

And the corresponding 'poster_view.ex':

```
def render("index.json", %{posts: posts}) do
  render("index.js", %{})
end
```

Note - I'm not passing posts into the template until I get the rendering to work.

Here is the js that gets triggered 'index.js.eex':

```
$("#foobar").append("<%= escape_javascript(render("foobar.html", %{})) %>");
```

And the template I'm trying to render 'foobar.html.eex':

```
<h2>i was placed dynamically</h2>
```

And the template I'm trying to render 'foobar.html.eex' on:

```
<div id="foobar"></div>
```

And the error I'm seeing:

```
[info] Sent 500 in 8ms
[error] #PID<0.994.0> running Blog.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/posters
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {:safe, [[["" | "$(\"#foobar\").append(\""] | "<h2>i was placed dynamically<\\/h2>\\n"] | "\");\n"]}
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:354: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
        (poison) lib/poison.ex:41: Poison.encode!/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:642: Phoenix.Controller.do_render/4
        (blog) web/controllers/poster_controller.ex:1: Blog.PosterController.action/2
        (blog) web/controllers/poster_controller.ex:1: Blog.PosterController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (blog) lib/blog/endpoint.ex:1: Blog.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (blog) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Blog.Router.dispatch/2
        (blog) web/router.ex:1: Blog.Router.do_call/2
        (blog) lib/blog/endpoint.ex:1: Blog.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (blog) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Blog.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (blog) lib/blog/endpoint.ex:1: Blog.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /Users/alang/projects/elixir/blog/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: Is there somewhere in the code where you try to parse or render this view as JSON ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me @Kernael I just updated the question.

Comment: Is that normal that your request is piping through "/api" although you are rendering html ? Just wondering

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm just mocking some stuff up right now - that will probably change once I get this working.

Comment: @happy_henry Can you please post the contents of `poster_controller.ex`?

Comment: @Dogbert I've added the corresponding 'poster_controller' action as well as view.

Comment: @happy_henry You are trying to render HTML stuff in an API, JSON formatted route. Hence `Poison`, an Elixir JSON library tries to parse your HTML view as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$("#foobar").append("<%= escape_javascript(render('foobar.html')) %>");
```

Comment: Because `'` aren't strings in Elixir it throws an error too: 
`** (ArgumentError) render/2 expects template to be a string, got: 'foobar.html'`